# Selecting specific elements that contain extra attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm fairly new to XSLT, and was wondering how I could replace certain elements. Basically, I would like to replace **BR** elements that come with extra attributes, with just a plain **BR**. The XML is as follows:

```
<outer_element>
    <p>
        <font face="Arial">
            Invitations<br>
        </font>
        <font face="Arial">
            Charts<br>
        </font>
    </p>
    <span style="font-size:12pt;">
        <br clear="all" style="font-size:18pt;">
    </span>
<outer_element>
```

And below is part of the XSL :

```
<xsl:template match="//outer_element">
    <xsl:element name="outer_element">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name = "text">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, I don't know exactly whether it's a XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 solution that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input isn't valid XML/XHTML. The `br`s should be closed: `<br/>`. Also, the final end tag is also not a closing tag. 
If you are not expecting valid XHTML, have a look at https://jsoup.org/ or http://www.html-tidy.org/.

That out of the way: There is an XSLT pattern called [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) that recursively copies the input to the output, but lets you override the copy process for each element you want.

The basic pattern locks like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now add a template for `br` that copies only the element, not the attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
 <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

That should be it.

Comment: Regarding the `br`, that's how the data is coming, and don't really have control over that. As for the rest of the solution, will that apply to the entire XML, not just within the "outer_element"? I've only copied the relevant scope of the XML for this question.

Comment: It will apply to the whole XML. You won't be able to use XSLT on this input, as it is not well-formed XML. If you want to use XSLT, you'll need to clean it up first, see jsoup or HTML tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple template:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="br">
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And this will include the br elements like `<BR clear="all" style="font-size:12pt;">`? And where should I place this, under `<xsl:value-of select "." />` ?

Comment: @RudyM, yes, it will include all `br` elements (with and without attributes). I've updated my answer with a complete template.